# Thymeleaf dependency causes "Error: Could not find or load main class" in Spring tool suite

Tags: java, spring, maven, pom.xml, thymeleaf

I've just downloaded STS and started some maven project and it worked properly, but when I start using thymeleaf it doesn't work.

I see an exclamation mark on the project name, and I get this error **Error: Could not find or load main class**.

I tried adding its dependencies by myself in the POM, I get that error and it goes away once I remove them!

I also tried creating a "Spring Starter Project" and choosing dependencies "Web and Thymeleaf" to be added, right after the project is created I see a syntax error in the POM in the test dependency **Failure to transfer org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar**

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

and when I remove it and its class, I get the same error above.

here is my POM now:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>demo-2</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>demo-2</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>


</project>
```

Comment: Can you post your stack trace?

Comment: I didn't add anything or any classes, I just run the main class that is automatically generated.
The only error line I get in the console is **Error: Could not find or load main class com.example.Demo2Application**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved after removing failed downloads:

from CMD:

```
cd %userprofile%\.m2\repository
for /r %i in (*.lastUpdated) do del %i
```

then updating the project.

It re-downloaded the dependencies and it worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try to update your maven repository, try first:

```
mvn dependency:purge-local-repository
```

> Description:
>
> When run on a project, remove the project dependencies from the local
>   repository, and optionally re-resolve them. Outside of a project,
>   remove the manually given dependencies.

and then try:

```
mvn dependency:copy-dependencies
```

> Description:
>
> Goal that copies the project dependencies from the repository to a
>   defined location.

It seems to me that your local Maven repository doesn't include the thymeleaf dependecy.

Comment: It didn't work .. but thanks, I found my answer by removing failed downloads.